# Problem with the 3D view in QGIS when plotting polygons

Tags: qgis, 3d-map

I have a polygon shapefile (projected in meters) which I want to to view it in 3D using the `3D Map Views`. I attached an image of what the shp looks like in 2D (you can see I added a basemap as well which I would like to be included in the 3D view scene).
[image: 2D image]
The extrusion is based on a column of the attribute table called *height* (Layer properties -> 3D view -> the icon next to Extrusion -> Data defined override -> Field type -> height).
[image: properties]
You can see in the next image attached that not only the colour ramp isn't displayed but most of the basemap is disappeared as well.
[image: 3d view]
How can I include the colour ramp for the polygon in the `3D view` as well as the whole basemap?

I am using `QGIS` 3.28.13 (LTR) and Windows 11 Home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the plugin called `qgis2threejs` to achive the desired results. Below is picture of the results
[image: results]

To extrude the polygon I had to change the settings of the polygon showed below.
[image: settings]